# What is the meaning of $\vec A \cdot \nabla$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Looking at the [application of divergence in Cartesian coordinates in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Application_in_Cartesian_coordinates)
I was wondering about the meaning of $\vec A \cdot \nabla$?

This dot product is found at the vector cross product identity:
$\nabla \times (\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) = \mathbf{A} (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}) - \mathbf{B} (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}) + (\mathbf{B} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{A} - (\mathbf{A} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{B}$

Comment: Where in that section do you see $\vec A\cdot \nabla$?  I only see $\nabla\cdot F$, which is just an alternative form for "$\mathrm{div}\,F$".

Comment: The 3rd and 4th addends the in the second [identity for vector cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Vector_cross_product).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\vec A \cdot \nabla = \sum_{i=1}^3 A_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$

Comment: Does this mean $(\vec A \cdot \nabla)\vec B = \sum_{i=1}^3 A_i (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\vec B)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you Robert and Shabat Shalom

Comment: So for any vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ we have commutativity of the scalar product: $\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}=\mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{a}$ but not with the del operator since $\mathbf{a}\cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla}\neq \boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot \mathbf{a}$??