What is the difference between $\nabla\cdot\vec{A}$ and $\vec{A}\cdot\nabla$?
$\nabla\times(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})=(\vec{B}\cdot\nabla)\vec{A}-\vec{B}(\nabla\cdot\vec{A})-(\vec{A}\cdot\nabla)\vec{B}+A(\nabla\cdot\vec{B})$

What is the difference between $\nabla\cdot\vec{A}$ and $\vec{A}\cdot\nabla$, even if $\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}=\vec{B}\cdot\vec{A}$.
I was able to get the terms $(\nabla\cdot\vec{B})\vec{A}-(\nabla\cdot\vec{A})\vec{B}$, but not able to get other two terms.
Also, if we expand the given equation with vector triple product, it gives different result:
$$∇×(A×B)= (∇.B)A - (∇.A)B,$$
where it is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. All your questions are answered with applications of the same fact: the components of $\vec{\nabla}$ are differential operators, not numbers, so they don't commute with functions.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120961/137524 for the meaning of $\vec{A}\cdot\nabla$.

The combination $\vec{F} \cdot \nabla$ is an operator.  When it is applied to a scalar field $g$ it is interpreted as:
$$
(\vec{F} \cdot \nabla){ {g}} := \vec{F} \cdot (\nabla g).
$$

This is analogous  in one-dimensional calculus to writing something like
$x^2\frac{d}{dx}$ to represent an operator that acts like this:
$$
\left(x^2\frac{d}{dx}\right) g(x) := x^2 g'(x) .
$$

Let $\vec{F}=U\hat{i}+V\hat{j}+W\hat{k}$ be a vector field. Here $U$, $V$ and $W$ are functions of $x$, $y$ and $z$.
$\nabla\cdot\vec{F}$ is the divergence of the vector field $\vec{F}$. We also use the notation $\text{div}\,\vec{F}$. It is NOT the dot product between two vectors. However, we use a notation that is quite similar to the dot product because their operations are quite similar.
We define $\text{div}\,\vec{F}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial W}{\partial z}$. If we define the vector differential operator (also called del or nabla) to be
$$\nabla=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix},$$
treating the vector differential operator as a vector, then $\nabla\cdot\vec{F}=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial W}{\partial z}$. Therefore we use the notation $\nabla\cdot\vec{F}$ to represent the divergence of the vector field $\vec{F}$. Again, this is just a notation, but not an actual dot product.
